# Can I disable a checkbox but still have its events triggered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

modified question after answer to use onclick="$( '#co1' ).attr( 'checked', true );" this works great with the disabled="disabled" attribute.....

but...The $aBoxes.change(function(){ does not seem to work with  onclick="$( '#co1' ).attr( 'checked', true );"

***Original question.....***

I was told that "When element is disabled, events are also disabled."

I would like to disable a checkbox, but have an event triggered by clicking a link.

I have this jquery:

```
var $aBoxes = $('#co1,#co2,#co3');
$aBoxes.change(function(){
  // check if all are checked based on if the number of checkboxes total
  // is equal to the number of checkboxes checked
  if ($aBoxes.length == $aBoxes.filter(':checked').length){
      $('#a1').hide();
      $('#a2').show();
  }else{
    $('#a1').show();
    $('#a2').hide();
  }
});


<div id="a1">
a1 div
</div>

<div id="a2" style="display:none;">
a2 div
</div>

<div class="content">
<ul>
<li>
<input disabled="disabled" id="co1" name="co1" type="checkbox" <?php if($mychecklist->co1==1) echo 'checked' ?>/>
<a href="http://bbc.co.uk" target="_blank" onclick="$( '#co1' ).attr( 'checked', true );">Link 1</a>
</li>
<li>
<input disabled="disabled" id="co2" name="co2" type="checkbox" <?php if($mychecklist->co2==1) echo 'checked' ?>/>
<a href="http://bbc.co.uk" target="_blank" onClick="$( '#co2' ).attr( 'checked', true );">Link 2</a>
</li>
<li>
<input disabled="disabled" id="co3" name="co3" type="checkbox" <?php if($mychecklist->co3==1) echo 'checked' ?>/>
<a href="http://bbc.co.uk" onClick="$( '#co3' ).attr( 'checked', true );">Link 3</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The onclick event on the link works great for checking the checkbox, but i would like to disable using disabled="diasabled" the checkbox and still have it working. This is so the user has to click on the link for the checkbox to be checked, rather than bypassing this step and checking the checkbox themselves.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you tried using the `change` event on your checkboxes instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear whether you want to check the disabled checkbox using an `<a>` link or trigger a click event attached to the checkbox. If the former, you can use `$( '#tt2' ).attr('checked', !$( '#tt2' ).attr('checked') )` to toggle the checkbox or `$( '#tt2' ).attr( 'checked', true )` to check it. If the latter, the click event should still run even if the checkbox is disabled.

---

If you need to *both* check the box and trigger an event just use both techniques.

```
<a href="http://bbc.co.uk" target="_blank" 
    onclick="$( '#co1' ).attr( 'checked', true ).trigger( 'change' );">
```

Comment: i have tried this before and it did work, but i also have another jquery function that shows/hides a div and your method does not seem to work with that. I will edit my question to show the full code.

Comment: Have another problem now, attr checked and trigger change work great but when the form is submitted it does not want to update the database. Is this something to do with the disabled checkbox? im using .....$newentry->co1=(isset($_POST['co1'])) ? 1 : 0;
$newentry->co2=(isset($_POST['co2'])) ? 1 : 0;
$newentry->co3=(isset($_POST['co3'])) ? 1 : 0;
.... to save the 3 checkboxes to the db

Comment: Disabled form fields aren't submitted with POST data. I think you'd be better off if instead of using a disabled checkbox you'd use a hidden form field to convey the data.

Comment: i need the disabled checkbox as i am using an image instead of the checbox (using this http://widowmaker.kiev.ua/checkbox/). Could i have a hidden field for each checkbox and use the links onclick="$( '#co1' ).attr( 'checked', true ).trigger( 'change' );"> to set the hidden value? What would i need to add to the onclick attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `readonly` attribute for your checkbox!

Comment: thanks for the response, but this did not work for me. I used @Juhana's answer